# Differentiation of Green's function and tensorial calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, tensors

Good morning / afternoon / evening,

I'm currently working with Mura's famous *Micromechanics of Defects in Solids* which relies heavily on multi-variables tensorial calculus. I'm currently trying to prove the following relation for all $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})^{T}$ in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ and $x' \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ :

$$C_{jlmn}G_{ij,l}(\overline{x}) = \frac{1}{8\pi (1-\nu)}\{(1-2\nu)\frac{\delta_{mi}\overline{x_{n}} + \delta_{ni}\overline{x_{m}} - \delta_{mn}\overline{x_{i}}}{\overline{x}^{3}} + 3\frac{\overline{x_{m}} \ \overline{x_{n}} \ \overline{x_{i}}}{\overline{x}^{5}}\}$$

Where $\overline{x} = |x - x'|$, $|.|$ is the euclidian norm, $(.)_{,i}$ denotes the derivation with respect to $x_{i}$, $\overline{x_{i}} = (x_{i} - x_{i}')$ for all $i$ and $G_{ij}$ and $C_{jlmn}$ are defined as :

$$G_{ij}(\overline{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi \mu}\frac{\delta{ij}}{\overline{x}} - \frac{1}{16\pi \mu (1-\nu)}\overline{x}_{,ij}$$

$$C_{jlmn} = \lambda \delta_{jl}\delta_{mn} + \mu(\delta_{jm}\delta{ln} + \delta_{jn}\delta_{lm}) $$

$C_{jlmn}$ is of course the stiffness tensor of an isotropic material, $\lambda, \mu, \nu $ are the Lamé's parameters and the Poisson's ratio of the material.

First, I have to differentiate functions of the euclidian norm with respect to coordinates of $x$, what I obtained was this :

$$|x-x'|_{,i} = \frac{(x_{i} - x_{i}')}{|x-x'|}$$

and

$$ \biggl( \frac{1}{|x-x'|^{p}} \biggl)_{,i} = -\frac{p(x_{i}-x_{i}')}{|x-x'|^{p+2}}$$

Using these identities **which I'm not sure are right** and multiplying $C_{jlmn}$ with $G_{ij,l}$ I obtain the following result :

$$C_{jlmn}G_{ij,l}(\overline{x}) = \biggl(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi \mu} + \frac{3\lambda}{16\pi \mu(1-\nu)}\biggl) \frac{-\overline{x_{i}}\delta_{mn}}{\overline{x}^{3}} - \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\overline{x_{n}}\delta_{im}}{\overline{x}^{3}}  - \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\overline{x_{m}}\delta_{in}}{\overline{x}^{3}} - \frac{3 \ \overline{x_{m}} \ \overline{x_{n}} \ \overline{x_{i}}}{8\pi (1-\nu)\overline{x}^{5}}$$

So basically, the last term is correct, so are the $\delta_{\alpha \beta}\overline{x_{\gamma}}$, but I can't factorize them the way they are in the formula I want to prove despite using the known identity 
$$ \lambda = \frac{2\mu \nu}{(1-2\nu)}$$
So here I am hoping for someone to see where my mistake is or notice something I didn't notice to finish the calculation...

Thanks a lot for your help, I have litteraly been spending more than 4 hours trying to prove this ^^

EDIT : It is important to note that I'm using Einstein's convention of summation over repeating indices.

Comment: $|x-x'|_{,i} = \frac{x_{i} - x_{i}'}{|x-x'|}$ and $\biggl( \frac{1}{|x-x'|^{p}} \biggl)_{,i} = -p\frac{x_{i}-x_{i}'}{|x-x'|^{p+2}}$ are correct.

Comment: How can $G_{ij}$ contain $\bar x_{,ij}$? Isn't that equal to $0$ (assuming $x'$ not depend on $x$)? Should it perhaps be $\bar x_{i,j}$?

Comment: @md2perpe $\overline{x} = |x - x'|$ so it is dependant on coordinates of $x$ :) Thanks for looking at my problem and thanks for your confirmation of the above formulas. My mistake can only be in the several products and sums but I don't know how to arrive to this factorization

Comment: @md2perpe In my calculations, I also found the identities $\delta_{ij}\overline{x}_{i} \overline{x}_{j} = \overline{x}^{2}$ and $\delta_{ij}\overline{x}_{j} = \overline{x}_{i}$. What puzzles me is that my factors are correct but not the coefficients and that at the same time one term of my result is one of the terms I'm supposed to find. It is important to note that I'm using Einstein's convention of summation over repeating indices.

Comment: Ah, you use $\bar x_i = x_{i} - x_i',$ but $\bar x$ doesn't denote $x - x'$. Instead it denotes the norm $|x - x'|.$

Comment: I get
$$\bar x_{,i} = \frac{\bar x_i}{\bar x}$$
$$\bar x_{,ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x^2 - \bar x_i \bar x_j}{\bar x^3}$$
$$\bar x_{,ijl} = - \frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x_l + \delta_{il} \bar x_j + \delta_{jl} \bar x_i}{\bar x^3} + \frac{3 \bar x_i \bar x_j \bar x_l}{\bar x^5}$$

Comment: Thus I get
$$G_{ij,l}(\bar x) =- \frac{1}{4\pi \mu}\frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x_l}{\bar x^3} - \frac{1}{16\pi \mu (1-\nu)}\left(- \frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x_l + \delta_{il} \bar x_j + \delta_{jl} \bar x_i}{\bar x^3} + \frac{3 \bar x_i \bar x_j \bar x_l}{\bar x^5}\right) \\
= - \frac{1}{4\pi\mu} \left(
\frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x_l}{\bar x^3}
+ \frac{1}{4(1-\nu)}\left(- \frac{\delta_{ij} \bar x_l + \delta_{il} \bar x_j + \delta_{jl} \bar x_i}{\bar x^3} + \frac{3 \bar x_i \bar x_j \bar x_l}{\bar x^5}
\right)
\right)
$$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes it's the notation adopted by Mura in his book. I dont get the same result for $G_{ij,l}$ but yours seems more realistic. I think that I found my mistake, when taking the derivative of $\overline{x}_{,i}$ with respect to $x_{j}$, I considered $\overline{x}_{i}$ as a constant so I missed the $\delta_{ij}\overline{x}^{2}$... I'll try again taking this into account and get back to you thanks a lot !